# Php Mysql insert stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

**My Stored Procedure:**

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS alphaindia.insertcoursedetails;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insertcoursedetails`( IN  `StartDate` DATE,IN  `ChurchName` VARCHAR(50), IN  `CourseTypeId` BIGINT, IN  `Participants` BIGINT, IN  `MxId` VARCHAR( 50 ) , IN  `DateCreated` DATE, IN  `LocationName` VARCHAR( 100 ) , IN  `LocationLatitude` VARCHAR( 50 ) , IN  `LocationLongitude` VARCHAR( 50 ) , IN  `LocationAddress` VARCHAR( 300 ) )
NO SQL
INSERT INTO coursedetails( StartDate, ChurchName, CourseTypeId, Participants, MxId, DateCreated, LocationName, LocationLatitude, LocationLongitude, LocationAddress ) 
ALUES (
        StartDate, ChurchName, CourseTypeId, Participants, MxId, DateCreated, LocationName, LocationLatitude, LocationLongitude, LocationAddress
      )
```

**PHP CODE:**

```
$date = date('d/m/Y');
echo $date;
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or
die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("alphaindia");
$result = mysql_query("Call insertcoursedetails('2/3/2014','$_SESSION['ChurchLead']','$_SESSION['courseid']','$_SESSION['NumbPart']','vini.katyal','2/3/2014','$_SESSION['shortname']','$_SESSION['lat'],'$_SESSION['long'],'$_SESSION['address']'");
if($result)
{
    echo("<br>Data Input OK");
} 
else
{
    echo("<br>Data Input Failed");
}
```

I am unable to insert data via the stored procedure in php. Please help

Comment: Your quotes are wrong in your query in php, double check them.

Comment: you have many syntax errors check that...

Comment: You are trying to insert date in dd-mm-yyyy format. MySQL date format is yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: OMG ........ Posted code has a lot of errors...:(

Comment: The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part. MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'.

Comment: @BrokenHeartღ I am new to Php :/

Comment: @vini I have posted the answer check that.

Answer (score 0):

In a double quoted string, PHP can evaluate variable names Like

```
echo "My name is $name";
```

But using arrays you must use curly braces to successfully evaluate your statement.
The following statement is valid

```
echo "My name is {$_SESSION['name']}";
```

You will get

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING
```

if you do

```
echo "My name is $_SESSION['name']";
```

And this is what is happening in your query.

Comment: Hi is this correct    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO coursedetails(StartDate, ChurchName, CourseTypeId, Participants, MxitId, DateCreated, LocationName, LocationLatitude, LocationLongitude, LocationAddress ) values('2/3/2014','{$_SESSION['ChurchLead']}',{$_SESSION['courseid']},'{$_SESSION['NumbPart']}','vini.katyal','2/3/2014','{$_SESSION['shortname']}','{$_SESSION['lat']}','{$_SESSION['long']}','{$_SESSION['address']}'");

Comment: What are 3 qoutes int the end? And mysql date format is `yyyy-mm-dd`. You can format input dates like `date("Y-m-d", strtotime($inputDateString))` Where `$inputDateString` could be "2/3/2014". Its better to use jqueryui datepicker to take date inputs. http://jqueryui.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your Procedure should be this:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS alphaindia.insertcoursedetails;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
   PROCEDURE `insertcoursedetails`(IN `StartDate` DATE,IN  `ChurchName` VARCHAR(50), IN  `CourseTypeId` BIGINT, IN  `Participants` BIGINT, IN  `MxId` VARCHAR( 50 ) , IN  `DateCreated` DATE, IN  `LocationName` VARCHAR( 100 ) , IN  `LocationLatitude` VARCHAR( 50 ) , IN  `LocationLongitude` VARCHAR( 50 ) , IN  `LocationAddress` VARCHAR( 300 ) )
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO coursedetails( StartDate, ChurchName, CourseTypeId, Participants, MxId, DateCreated, LocationName, LocationLatitude, LocationLongitude, LocationAddress ) 
VALUES (
        StartDate, ChurchName, CourseTypeId, Participants, MxId, DateCreated, LocationName, LocationLatitude, LocationLongitude, LocationAddress
      )
END$$
```

You need to add the `BEGIN` and `END` in the procedure.

Read more here for [Procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html).